# Make text invisible in printed version of the document - avoid color correction

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a simple "fill the gaps" excercise in html. There are gaps, looking like this:

> Earth closest star is _ _ _ _.

The gaps are not supposed to be fillable on the computer - the document is supposed to be printed with the gaps enpty. But they have a content so, when howered, answers may be checked.
I use border-bottom property to make the gaps. There is a text filled in the gaps but it is white, so the user only can see it on hover.

#### The CSS:

```
span.gap {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
span.gap:hover {
    color: gray;

}
```

#### The HTML:

```
Stephen Hawking is famous for his research of <span class="gap">black holes</span>.
Stackoverflow only helps you if you ask <span class="gap">simple questions</span>.
```

Browser seems to fix the color from white to black, so the gap content is visible in the printed document. How should I hide the text then?
I cannot use the `visibility` property, because the border must be visible.

Comment: Would you be opposed to using some jQuery to solve this? I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aFxKE/ -- See if it can do what you need.

Comment: Have you tried using any of the image replacement techniques?  http://jsfiddle.net/TZD84/

Comment: @cimmanon This is probably the most interesting solutions. And it seems to be the only possible without using multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of all of the image replacement techniques, there are a few that will work without adding extra elements.  All of them will require setting a width on the span if you want it to appear inline.

http://jsfiddle.net/TZD84/

```
span.gap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8em;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-indent: 110%;
}

span.gap:hover {
    color: gray;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

If you need to support older browsers, there's always the negative text-indent method

http://jsfiddle.net/TZD84/1/

```
span.gap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-indent: -10em;
}

span.gap:hover {
    color: gray;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I used. Pure CSS solution was very important for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media types to handle different display/media situations. I.e add something like this to your CSS:

```
@media print { .gap { /* add your styles */ }}
```

Also, in combination with this you could add a separate `span` that would display only for print. Like:

**HTML:**

```
Stackoverflow only helps you if you ask 
<span class="gap">simple questions</span>
<span class="print-gap"></span>.
```

**CSS:**

```
span.gap, span.print-gap {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
span.gap:hover {
    color: gray;
}
@media screen {
    span.print-gap { display: none; }
}
@media print { 
    span.gap { display: none; } 
    span.print-gap { display: inline-block; width: 100px; }
}
```

Comment: I'm really grateful for all your effort, and I will try this. But you know, the document itself is written by hand and is supposed to be light. So writing aditional spans is going to be annoying.
I can think of `for` loop to add them though.